# What are the requirements for reports to display in Hardware Dev Center Dashboard?

Tags: windows, driver, bsod, windows-error-reporting

I have created an account at Microsoft Windows Dev Center - Hardware and signed the Windows Error Reporting Agreement.

Then, I have introduced an null-pointer dereference to release signed driver that I used on my test computer and sent the BSoD report to Microsoft.

I have used the Microsoft Ecosystem Metadata Exchange to map my driver name and created the product groups.

From what I have read on the internet these should be all the requirements to get the report to display in the dashboard. The report was supposedly updated twice since the mapping took place.

I have mailed the wer as well and got "In general it will take 5 days." and later, when I explained that already two weeks have passed I got "Sorry for that let me work with WER team." and I haven't heard anything since then.

Is there some extra requirement I have missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently looks like that's all one have to do in order to receive the report.

Today my dashboard was updated with some real error that had 4 hits (reported from 4 different machines).

I have not received the report for null-pointer dereference. I guess the problem has happen on more than one machine to actually show up.